# PHP не видит файл

Tags: php, bash

Проблема: на баше написан скрипт, который в дальнейшем будет добавлен в крон, он проверяет есть ли в данной директории `.txt` файлы и добавляет полные пути до них в файл `query.log`.

Так же есть ещё один php скрипт, который должен считывать файлы из `query.log` и добавлять данные их них в базу данных, затем переименовывать этот файл (пусть будет `1.txt`) в файл `1.bkp`.

Проблема такая, когда я писал код для проверки всей этой системы, я вручную прописывал полный путь до файла и все работало крайне превосходно, но как только я стал брать пути из `query.log` php стал выдавать, что такой файл или директория не найдена. Я не могу понять в чем дело, но вот прилагаю коды, буду признателен за помощь:

**1) Bash код:**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/zsumo/testRsync/dataDemin/
find `pwd`/ | grep .txt > query.log
```

**2)php код:**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$dbconn=pg_connect("host=****Какой-то хост*** port=***Какой-то порт*** dbname=***Какое-то имя БД*** user=***Какое-то имя пользователя password=***Какой-то пароль***") or die('Could not connect' . pg_last_error());
$listOfTXT=file('/home/zsumo/testRsync/dataDemin/query.log');
foreach ($listOfTXT as $value){
     $stringOfFile=file($value);
    foreach($stringOfFile as $lineOfFile){
            $element=explode("\t", $lineOfFile);
            $query="INSERT INTO kppo (data1, data2, data3) VALUES ('$element[0]', 'element[1]', element[2]);
            pg_query($query);
    }
    $renameFile=substr_replace($fileTXT, 'bkp', -4);
    rename($fileTXT, $renameFile);
}
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: Это конечно не касается причин почему не работает, но у вас странный `.sh`. `grep .txt` найдет не только файлы с расширением txt, но и например abc.txtx и даже abtxte.bin, потому как `.` у grep - заменитель любого символа. `find \`pwd\`/ -name "*.txt"` гораздо надежнее выберет именно .txt файлы

Comment: Спасибо за замечание))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `file()` в php создает массив строк из этого файла, причем в конце строк остаются переводы кареток. В этом легко убедится:

```
$listOfTXT=file('/home/zsumo/testRsync/dataDemin/query.log');
foreach ($listOfTXT as $value) {  print "'$value'"; }
```

Выведет что то вроде

```
'file1
''file2
''file3
'
```

Как видим, кавычка в конце имени файлы уехала на новую строку ...

Следовательно нам надо убрать переводы кареток из строк массива, потому как они считаются значимыми символами имени файла и такого файла конечно не находится.

Т.е. ваш цикл чтения имен файлов должен выглядеть так:

```
foreach ($listOfTXT as $value){
 $stringOfFile=file(str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$value));
 ....
}
```

Обратите внимание, ваш `explode("\t")` так же никуда не убирает переводы кареток из строк читаемого файла и у последнего элемента массива в конце перевод каретки останется ...